# Actual data isn't insert in MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql

I working with Biometric Device based attendance system. When user punch the system then data will retrieved device to gateway. I used Pycharm for retrieved device data. Normally data will show in my console but when i try to insert data in MYSQL then data will not insert properly. I want to store only Serial no, User ID, Attendance time. But after insert value in mysql database then user id cannot store properly.Given bellow MYSQL database table data:

```
Serial no           User ID                  Attendance time
1                     1                      2016-10-31 12:55:19
2                     1                      2016-10-24 11:53:34
3                     1                      2016-10-24 12:06:1
4                     1                      2016-10-24 12:09:48
5                     2                      2016-10-24 12:09:45
6                     2                      2016-10-24 12:09:47
```

This user id is not valid. My device have some user id like: (999,1,4,8,8) 
I can't understand this problem. Given bellow the code:

```
conn = zk.connect()
    attandance= conn.get_attendance()
    for data in attandance:
        userId= data.user_id
        enrty_time= data.timestamp

        print("User id:", userId)
        print("Punch:", data.punch)
        print("Entry time:", data.timestamp)

        print("Status:",data.status)
        my_sql_connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="bio")
        myCursor = my_sql_connection.cursor()
        sql = """INSERT INTO power(id,time) VALUES('%s','%s')""" % (userId,enrty_time)
        myCursor.execute(sql)
        print("insert successfully")

        my_sql_connection.commit()
        my_sql_connection.close()
```

Comment: what type of column is used to store userId ?

Comment: Serial= int(primary) id= (String), time= (DateTime)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. AND there is no such thing as a string datatype in mysql please add your table definition.

Comment: Don't use string interpolation, it's prone to SQL injection. Your MySQL driver likely allows you to do queries like `execute("""... VALUES(%s, %s)""", (userId, entry_time))`. This looks almost the same, but uses prepared statements and placeholders instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this. You can use '?' as a placeholder instead of '%s', it's more dynamic.

```
myCursor = my_sql_connection.cursor()
myCursor.execute('insert into power(id,time) values(?,?);', (userId, enrty_time))
my_sql_connection.commit()
```